# Need to add Active Directory User to SQL Server Active Directory Group

Tags: sql-server

I have an AD group aus/query where I need to add an individual AD user aus/dsmith to this group.  I do not want to add individual logins to my SQL Server.

How to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to add the user as a member of the AD aus/query group? This is done through AD Computers and Users. If you're asking something else, [edit] your question and make it clear what you're asking. (I don't see how this is a programming question in either case, so you'll need to clarify that as well, or your question is off-topic here.)

Comment: Answers my question.

Comment: Most probably you will not have Active Directory privileges to add a member to a group, so you may need to talk with your domain administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it outside of SQL Server.
For example you can use following powershell commandlet:

```
Add-ADGroupMember query dsmith
```

You can find more about it at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=winserver2012-ps